# primary action of menu in ios 16 not working

Tags: swiftui, ios16

Does anyone know why the primary action of Menus in SwiftUI is not working since iOS 16 beta?

```
    Menu {
       Button {
          print("action 1")
       } label: {
          Text("Action 1")
       }
    } label: {
       Text("Menu")
    } primaryAction: {
       print("primary")
    }
```

Comment: Confirm this. It looks like a bug - file feedback to Apple.

Comment: thanks, so i am not the only one experiencing this bug

Comment: Still experiencing this. Anyone found a solution? It worked.. and now it doesn't

Comment: Just came across this issue in iOS 16.